# Why are virtual functions preferable over derived class objects?

Tags: c++, virtual-functions

So I'm new to learning about virtual functions, and I'm following online tutorials and I can't seem to find an answer to my question. I want to ask why using virtual functions below by setting base class objects to point to derived class objects, is preferable to just using the derived class objects themselves to access the functions?

It seems that I get the same output either way, and it seems creating base class objects and virtual functions are extra steps. I saw a similar example to this on an online tutorial which claimed virtual functions made coding easier but I don't quite see the benefit in this example?

I read online that:

> The main advantage of virtual functions are that they directly support object oriented programming. When you declare a function as virtual you're saying that exactly what code is executed depends on the type of the object you call it against.

But it seems this is already the case using derived objects, and that creating base class objects is unnecessary? I'm sure that I'm missing something obvious so I would really appreciate any help. I showed an example code I wrote below which is similar to what I've seen when detailing virtual functions:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//base class
class Shape {

public:
virtual void draw()=0;  //pure virtual function
};

//derived classes
class Square : public Shape {

public:
void draw() {
    cout << "Draw square" << endl;
    }

};

class Circle : public Shape {

public:
void draw() {
    cout << "Draw circle " << endl;
    }

};

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////
int main()
{
Square so;  //create derived class objects
Circle co;

Shape* shape1 = &so;  //setting base class objects as pointers to derived objects
Shape* shape2 = &co;


shape1->draw();  //using base class objects to access derived class
shape2->draw();

so.draw();  //using derived class objects
co.draw();

}
```

Comment: Given `Shape *create()`, what will `create()->draw()` output? Assume that `create` comes from external DLL that is loaded at runtime.

Comment: Classes inheriting from base classes with virtual functions are also derived. Non-virtual functions won't support virtual dispatch though, so you can't call a derived class' functions through a base class pointer/reference where those functions are not virtual.

Comment: Have you tried this same example without `virtual`? Note that you'll have to implement `Shape::draw` to try this. The purpose of `virtual` should be immediately clear.

Comment: Because the example tried to be so basic that it missed the point. It should have used a function instead that takes a `Shape*` or `Shape&` argument to show the usefulness.

Comment: I decided to create a new `Shape` called `Triangle`. Any function that takes a `Shape` can use my new class automatically.

Comment: "_I want to ask why using virtual functions below by setting base class objects to point to derived class objects, is preferable to just using the derived class objects themselves to access the functions?_" Yes, in your example, there's no need for that. However, imagine having `std::vector<Shape*>`, whose contents are determined based on the user input, during runtime. You wouldn't be able to use the instances of derived objects directly as easily, then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The huge benefit that you get for using the base class pointer type and virtual functions is that you can have one single list that contains several different types of `Shape` and you can process them all in a single function where they will all have different behaviors due to their derived types.

As an example, I modified your code by adding the function `DrawAllShapes` that takes in a `vector<Shapes*>&`. (Be careful of using raw pointers. You really should use `vector<std::unique_ptr<Shape>>&`here or something like that.

You have incredible flexibility with this pattern that lets you call the same function on a collection of base class pointer objects but results in different behavior for every object in the collection depending on its derived type.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//base class
class Shape {

public:
    virtual void draw() = 0;  //pure virtual function
};

//derived classes
class Square : public Shape {

public:
    void draw() {
        cout << "Draw square" << endl;
    }

};

class Circle : public Shape {

public:
    void draw() {
        cout << "Draw circle " << endl;
    }

};

void DrawAllShapes(std::vector<Shape*>& shapes) {
    for (int i = 0; i < shapes.size(); ++i) {
        shapes[i]->draw();
    }
}

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////
int main()
{
    std::vector<Shape*> shapeVec{ new Square, new Circle, new Square, new Square, new Circle };
    DrawAllShapes(shapeVec);

    system("pause");
}
```

Also, imagine if you were using a prebuilt graphical library that already had a Shape class and several shapes defined. What if you wanted to add your own new type of Shape and have it work perfectly with all of the library's functions? All you would have to do is create your own derived class and implement all of the necessary virtual functions exposed by the library's Shape class and then you've literally extended the library beyond its original capabilities.

Comment: So from my understanding of your answer, the benefit is that functions which require objects as their inputs can be used to access every derived class using virtual functions and base class pointer objects rather than having to create a new function for each type of derived class object?

Comment: @Andrew Yes that's correct. Any external code operating on a collection of base class pointers doesn't have to know anything about the derived class details. It can simply use the virtual member functions exposed in the base class to operate on each instance and the compiler has already set up the code to automatically forward those base class virtual function calls to the proper derived class.

Comment: @Andrew Also, imagine if you were using a prebuilt graphical library that had a Shape class and several shapes defined. What if you wanted to add your own new type of Shape and have it work perfectly with all of the library's functions? All you would have to do is create your own derived class and implement all of the necessary virtual functions exposed by the library's Shape class and then you've literally extended the library beyond its original capabilities.

Comment: So dynamic polymorphism allows simple code extension? And lastly, could the user determine the type of derived class the base class pointer objects are associated with i.e. the user decides the contents of the array in your example? i could see how that would make the code very flexible.

Comment: @Andrew Yes the user has full control over that. Also if you have a special use case where you need to access non-virtual functions belonging to the derived class, and if you know or check during runtime the derived type referred to by the base class pointer, then you can cast the base pointer to the derived pointer and access the derived class's specific properties. Sometimes this is needed, but try to avoid this practice because you can end up with code littered with typecasts that doesn't fully utilize polymorphism.